# New to Robolectric, first test

Tags: java, android, robolectric

Hi I'm trying to get into testing using Robolectric.
I've set up a button that simply sets another views visibility to visible and I'm trying to test to see if that has occurred. But my test always fails.
this is what I have so far:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

    private MainAct mActivity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainAct.class).create().get();
    }


    @Test
    public void myActivityAppearsAsExpectedInitially() {
        //mActivity.fab.performClick();

        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        floatingActionButton.performClick();

        TextView appbar = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.searchheader);
        assertThat(appbar).hasText("aidanmack");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately according to the test, the visibility is still set to "gone".

But that isn't the case when I run the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I might be wrong, but you actually are never calling the click event of your button in the test, `button.performClick()`.

Comment: Hmm OK, any Ideas what I should be doing for the permclick to do code its supposed to do?

Comment: `mActivity.findViewById(R.id.your_button).performClick()`?

Comment: Thanks but I tried that, just the same. Ive updated my question to show the entire test...

Comment: Does the click work? You can check the performClick() return value to be true or debug your application if the click event is triggered and calls the expected code fragment.

Comment: @nenick I've seen you've contributed to robolectric - are these types of tests supported? I imagined you'd need to run these on a device as instrumentation tests.

Comment: @ataulm Do you mean toggling the visibility of layout elements? Yes this is supported by robolectric.

Comment: @nenick honestly I'm unsure what I meant: I've used robolectric only to test my classes that have android dependencies that cannot be mocked - I've never seen it being used to test an actual activity.

Comment: @ataulm I created a project to show how and what can be tested with robolectic. https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template Just tell me if you miss some explanation on that project

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric allows you to run tests on the JVM.

The instrumentation test you're trying to run must be performed on a device or emulator using `connectedAndroidTest` - check out the Espresso framework.

Comment: He is writing unit tests with robolectric, not instrumentation tests.